# Why is it necessary to terminate a process when the child process has already ignored the SIGINT signal?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

My English is not good.

I'm reading the code from ansible 1.1
The following is taken from "ansible-1.1/lib/ansible/runner/__init__.py"

```
def _executor_hook(job_queue, result_queue):

    # attempt workaround of https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns/issues/17
    # this function also not present in CentOS 6
    if HAS_ATFORK:
        atfork()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    while not job_queue.empty():
        try:
            host = job_queue.get(block=False)
            result_queue.put(multiprocessing_runner._executor(host))
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()

class Runner(object):
    # ...
    def _parallel_exec(self, hosts):
        ''' handles mulitprocessing when more than 1 fork is required '''

        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        job_queue = manager.Queue()
        for host in hosts:
            job_queue.put(host)
        result_queue = manager.Queue()

        workers = []
        for i in range(self.forks):
            prc = multiprocessing.Process(target=_executor_hook,
                args=(job_queue, result_queue))
            prc.start()
            workers.append(prc)

        try:
            for worker in workers:
                worker.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            for worker in workers:
                worker.terminate()
                worker.join()
```

When an error is caught, the terminate method is also called.
What is the difference between this and a direct pass?

```
try:
    for worker in workers:
        worker.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This lets the workers do their thing until they're done

```py
try:
  for worker in workers:
    worker.join()
```

This gets called when you press ctrl+c

```py
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  for worker in workers:
    worker.terminate()
    worker.join()
```

You are basically telling the program: "Don't let the workers finish their stuff, shut them down and get me out of here NOW"

Answer (score 0):

On SIGINT, it will tell each worker to terminate, but then it *still waits for them all to exit* (completing whatever they do on termination) before it exits itself.

Comment: But in function _executor_hook, it set SIGINT to SIG_IGN. SIGINT will be ignored